# How to test source_gen annotation builders using testBuilder?

Tags: dart

I have a code generator made using [source_gen](https://github.com/dart-lang/source_gen). It is working properly, but I would like to add tests.

I followed the documentation and took inspiration from [built_value](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/blob/12b586cd952d4d106bec122da4b3f1020d4c127a/built_value_generator/test/enum_class_generator_test.dart) by using `testBuilder` from [build_test](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/tree/master/build_test).

The problem is, when using `testBuilder`, it cannot properly resolve imports. And therefore throws an error and doesn't trigger my generator.

> Error: line 1, column 91 of asset:example/lib/src/truc.dart: Could not resolve annotation for foo() → dynamic\n'

Here's my current test attempt :

```
import 'package:source_gen/source_gen.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:build_test/build_test.dart';
import 'package:my_gen/my_gen.dart';

const input = {
  "example|lib/src/foo.dart": '''
import 'package:my_gen/my_gen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

@stateless
Widget foo() {
  return Center();
}
'''
};

void main() {
  test('', () async {
    await testBuilder(SharedPartBuilder([MyGenerator], "stateless"), input, outputs: {
      "example|lib/src/foo.stateless.g.part": '''
// **************************************************************************
// StatelessGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return foo();
  }
}
'''
    });
  });
}
```

How can I make `testBuilder` to properly resolve import; and ultimately test by generator?

Answer (score 1):

Look at what we do in `json_serializable` - https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/blob/master/json_serializable/test/json_serializable_test.dart

We don't use `build_test`. Instead we have a utility library that gets a library reader you can use for testing - https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/blob/master/json_serializable/test/analysis_utils.dart

Comment: Actually yeah, I based myself on `built_value`. Don't know why I said `json_serializable`

Comment: But that's interesting. If I don't get `build_test` working I'll try that, thanks